# pip install mysqlclient issues

Tags: python, django, linux, host

when I try to use pip install mysqlclient issues command
I get this error

```html
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting issues  Downloading issues-0.0.0.tar.gz (858 bytes)  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... doneBuilding wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient, issues  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed: No such file or directory
      [end of output]
```

Comment: Do you have `gcc` installed on your device?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/  "You may need to install the Python 3 and MySQL development headers and libraries" - did you do that?

Comment: Thankyou guys
it was my server problem
GCC permeation is the solution